# Manipulate elements of arrays dynamically without for loop in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array in ruby and i want to change the values of it's elements dynamically depending on a particular attribute. Suppose i have an array,

```
array = [123,134,145,515]
```

And i want to manipulate this elements like getting all the elements multiplied by a parameter, how can i get it done without having to do it explicitly each time using for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use something like the `collect` method in ruby for arrays.

You can write a method which can be called whenever required passing the array and parameter as argument.

For instance you can write a method similar to this ;

```
array = [123,134,145,515]
parameter_value = 2
```

Now, depending on the requirement you can define a method like this :

```
  array.collect {|x| x * parameter_value}
```

In this case, this would return an array similar to this :

```
array = [246, 268, 290, 1030]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this:

```
array = [123,134,145,515]
n = <any number>

array1 =array.map{|a| a * n}
```

or

```
array.map!{|a| a * n} #which modify the array object itself
```

Comment: it should have been 'array =array.map{|a| a * n}' why should i have a new array??

Comment: @Sayuj : hai sayuj !! where you from?? join my chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-rails-enterprise-apps-developers

Comment: @Seane. There are are a lot of reasons to create objects instead of updating them, map is generally preferrable. Check "functional programming" in google.

Comment: @Sayuj, your answer is the more Ruby-ish. Nice!